# Azure Powershell create a web app with deployment from Bitbucket private repo

Tags: git, powershell, azure, bitbucket, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to create an azure web app using powershell script. I am able to create it without any problem. But when i try to use private repo (bitbucket) for deployment using powershell script. i am getting errors, this is what happens.

```
Set-AzureRmResource : The pipeline has been stopped.
At line:30 char:1
+ Set-AzureRmResource -PropertyObject $PropertiesObject -ResourceGroupN ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Set-AzureRmResource], PipelineStoppedException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.SetAzureResourceCmdlet
Set-AzureRmResource : {"Message":"An error has occurred."}
At line:30 char:1
+ Set-AzureRmResource -PropertyObject $PropertiesObject -ResourceGroupN ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Set-AzureRmResource], ErrorResponseMessageException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
InternalServerError,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.SetAzureResourceCmdlet
```

The above error occurs when i reach the point to deploy code from remote repository.
Now, i will show what i have did

```
$gitrepo="https://xxxxx@bitbucket.org/companyName/xx-x-demo.git"
$webappname="mywebapp$(Get-Random)"
$location="Southeast Asia"

# Create a resource group.
New-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name myResourceGroup -Location $location

# Create an App Service plan in Free tier.
New-AzureRmAppServicePlan -Name $webappname -Location $location `
-ResourceGroupName myResourceGroup -Tier Free

# Create a web app.

New-AzureRmWebApp -Name $webappname -Location $location -AppServicePlan $webappname `
-ResourceGroupName myResourceGroup

# SET Bitbucket
$PropertiesObject = @{
   token= 'xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxx=';
   tokenSecret= 'xxxxxxxxxx'; 
   refreshToken= 'xxxxxxxxxxxx';
}

Set-AzureRmResource -PropertyObject $PropertiesObject -ResourceId /providers/Microsoft.Web/sourcecontrols/Bitbucket -ApiVersion 2015-08-01 -Force

# Configure Bitbucket deployment from your Bitbucket repo and deploy once.
$PropertiesObject = @{
    repoUrl = "$gitrepo";
    branch = "master";
}

Set-AzureRmResource -PropertyObject $PropertiesObject -ResourceGroupName myResourceGroup `
-ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/sourcecontrols -ResourceName $webappname/web `
-ApiVersion 2015-08-01 -Force
```

I have referred [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/scripts/app-service-powershell-continuous-deployment-github) tutorial from microsoft and it is for github. The tokens which i have included are generated with a curl request from bitbucket. Here is the request i made

```
curl -X POST -u "{client_id}:{client_secret}" \
https://bitbucket.org/site/oauth2/access_token \
-d grant_type=client_credentials
```

and it returns access token and refresh token that i have used in script. and secret i have used in script is client_secret.

I have referred to [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b8af27c0-d936-4e19-899a-d36054e855b8/managing-web-app-deployment-sources-through-c-api?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview) question but no help.

I am sure that the tokens i am sending with script are valid

Comment: there could be limitations imposed on your app when deploying - are you able to get further logging details of the error?

Comment: @BKSpurgeon i am able to successfully deploy, using github public repo which means there is no limitation as such (i think). and no i am not able to get any further logging details of this error. if there is a way to get verbose, please let me know how i can do it.

Comment: Looks promising https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio

Comment: @BKSpurgeon i check deployment logs from kudu console, but no luck, there are no logs for deployment, so it seems like there is issue before it tries to deploy on azure web app. any thoughts ?

Comment: ¯\_(ツ)_/¯       if the above doesn't work - i don't know bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after a lot of google searching i could not find a solution for bitbucket, so i changed my approach. Now, I am using FTP to deploy code on newly created web app. here is the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/scripts/app-service-powershell-deploy-ftp?toc=%2Fpowershell%2Fmodule%2Ftoc.json) if some one get stuck. Hope it help someone.